# Codeigniter - Botman - Conversations method not replying

Tags: php, codeigniter, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, botman

I'm using [Botman 2.0](https://botman.io/2.0/conversations) and [Codeigniter 3.1.6](https://www.codeigniter.com/download)

[Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) & FB Webhook setup successfully..

Did a simple hears & reply method, working good :

```
$this->botman->hears('foo','HelloWorld@handleFoo');
$this->botman->hears('hello',function($bot){
    $bot->reply('bye~');
 });
```

[image]

But when using [Botman's conversation method](https://botman.io/2.0/conversations), then Bot is not replying...my conversation code as below:

```
$this->load->library('BotConversations/OnboardingConversation');
$this->botman->hears('sup', function($bot) {
    $bot->startConversation(OnboardingConversation);
});
// Listen
$this->botman->listen();
```

[image]

anyhow, I've follow [Botman's Cache conf](https://botman.io/2.0/cache-drivers)'s guide to setup Cache via Codeigniter method

Below are some of my test files:

- [Controller](http://01-px.com/controller.txt)
- [Class](http://01-px.com/OnboadringConversation.txt)

appreciate your help! thanks....

Comment: Hi @Mavichow, How did you setup the Botman and CodeIgniter, I am trying setup, but so far  this does no work, Could you give some advices for find the solution?

Comment: Hi @Mavichow, Is required setup Cache on Codeigniter to that the botman works correctly?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't need any cache setup on Codeigniter, I follow the documentation @ https://botman.io/2.0/installation#installation via Composer Installation

Comment: I believe you need to setup the correct credential on your Driver/Provider, the provider I use is facebook and I'm referring to https://botman.io/2.0/driver-facebook-messenger

Comment: I've installed https://ngrok.com/ on my machine as well to tunnel HTTPS in local environment

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Currently I had complete setup on my own server(HTTPS) and this does no work. But I integrated another fan page of test and the bot app of test with NodeJS and they work very good.  I am not sure to happen with Botman. And also, I followed the steps of the documentation in botman.io.

Comment: A thing more, Is need to send request from postman app or nrok? or I could send from messenger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177298/discussion-between-wilfredonoyola-and-mavichow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine right now, I overlook on a simple syntax issue...
updated my code as below :

```
$this->botman->hears('sup', function($bot) {
    $bot->startConversation(New OnboardingConversation);
});
```